# How to access abstract class methods in zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Hii..

How can I access abstract class methods in zend form?

I have the following class in library folder

abstract class Adx_Controller_Standard extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
public function getSelectedAdvertiser()
    {
        return value;
    }

}

I want to access getSelectAdvertiser() function in Module(Advertiser) -> Forms (AddAdvertiser.php) which is Zend Form.

How can I do this ?? please help!!

Comment: Please rephrase your question; the two 'answers' so far are simply return questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be more specific here? Do you mean how can you access an abstract method from another class in a Zend_Form subclass?

You cannot instantiate abstract classes directly but you can access them if they are declared static or if you subclass the abstract class and then instantiate it.

Comment: Can you declare getSelectedAdvertiser() static? Then you can access it using Adx_Controller_Standard::getSelectedAdvertiser() If not then you need to create a new class extending Adx_Controller_Standard and instantiate this.

Answer (score 2):

can you elaborate? you could use reflection to interrogate the class.

you have to extend an abstract class and overload any abstract methods - if its the abstract methods you are interested in then unfortunately there is nothing to be interested in - you HAVE to write your concrete implementation for them yourself at some point (or rather these methods WILL be written in a child object somewhere along the line).